# Find numeric value of a digit character in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, numbers, char

There are several ranges in Unicode characters that represent digits, for which `char.IsDigit` returns `true`. For example:

```
bool b1 = char.IsDigit('\uFF12');    // full-width '2' -> true
bool b2 = char.IsDigit('\u0665');    // true
bool b3 = char.IsDigit('5');         // true
```

I'm looking for a way to get the numeric equivalent of such characters. Note that `int.Parse(...)` DOES NOT work, as it expects the input characters to be in the base unicode range ('0' .. '9').

This is equivalent to Java's `Character.digit(...)` behavior.

Since the .NET framework's `char.IsDigit` method correctly identifies such characters as digits, I'm expecting it to have this functionality as well, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried [`Char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz.aspx)? (I'm just booting up my Windows laptop to check :)

EDIT: Just tried it - looks like it works:

```
Console.WriteLine(char.GetNumericValue('\uFF12'));  // 2
Console.WriteLine(char.GetNumericValue('\u0665'));  // 5
Console.WriteLine(char.GetNumericValue('5'));       // 5
```

Note that this *doesn't* just include digits - it's any numeric character. However, `IsDigit` *is* just for digits. For example:

```
// U+00BD is the Unicode "vulgar fraction one half" character
Console.WriteLine(char.IsDigit('\u00bd'));         // False
Console.WriteLine(char.GetNumericValue('\u00bd')); // 0.5
```

Comment: Yes, just tried it too. It works, thanks. I've checked the whole methods on `char` class, it's embarrassing that I've overlooked this one...

Comment: Even Jon Skeet's laptops boot faster ;)